# What's the fastest way to query for a free ID in an SQLite table?

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, primary-key

I heard that SQLite has special processing for ID columns and is stored with a special type, "PRIMARY NUMERIC KEY".

So what's the fastest query I can write to fetch a free ID? Assuming that all ID's before that one are occupied. Is MAX(id) the best I can get?

Comment: Why not just use AUTONUMBER instead?

Comment: Yes but I want to know the new number BEFORE insertion.

Comment: Why do you need to know it before you insert?

Comment: Because my MVC is implemented such that the data insertion routines never touch the actual DB, only queue up a command that will do so later, although the ID must be preallocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to preallocate IDs, create a table that stores last allocated ID for every table. Preallocate an ID from it by incrementing the appropriate value and committing the change, then use it as needed, or forget.

This is a bit like sequences work in Oracle and Postgres.